# Replacing Wygwam p tag with h1 also adds an empty p

Tags: wygwam, low-replace

I have the following to strip out the p tags that are auto generated by Wygwam. For some reason it's not happening for me!

```
<h1>{exp:low_replace find="<p>"}{hero_article:articles_title}{/exp:low_replace}</h1>
```

This outputs an empty paragraph tag within the h1 tags.

Any idea why this might be? I've also tried `parse="outward"`.

Comment: Couple questions: 1) Why are you using Wygwam for a title? Wouldn't a text field make more sense? 2) Why is the custom field prefixed with `hero_article:`?

Answer (score 3):

You might want to remove the closing `</p>` as well:

```
{exp:low_replace find="<p>|</p>" multiple="yes"} ... {/exp:low_replace}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd be better off using [Streeng](https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/streeng) in this way:

```
{exp:streeng allowed="h1" parse="inward"}<h1>{hero_article:articles_title}</h1>{/exp:streeng}
```